# The class 'App\Document\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony4

I have just put in place mongodb with symfony4.1.

When I want to persist a simple User in the database, I got this error (title) :

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "The class 'App\Document\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

[image]

Here my controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/mongoTest")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @param DocumentManager $dm
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function mongoTest(DocumentManager $dm)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setEmail("hello@medium.com");
    $user->setFirstname("Matt");
    $user->setLastname("Matt");
    $user->setPassword(md5("123456"));
    $dm->persist($user);
    $dm->flush();
    return new JsonResponse(array('Status' => 'OK'));
}
```

Config :

```html
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: "%mongodb_server%"
      options: {}
  default_database: "%mongodb_database_name%"
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
  default_commit_options: ~
```

Here my Document :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="date")
     */
    protected $create_date;

    // ...
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

I do not use bundles.

```html
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
      server: "%mongodb_server%"
      options: {}
  default_database: "%mongodb_database_name%"
  document_managers:
    default:
      mappings:
        # ...
        App:
          type: annotation
          dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Document"
          is_bundle: false
          prefix: App\Document
          alias: App
  default_commit_options: ~
```